# how to get values from url and view them on map as markers in android

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have JSON url which has a response like

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "response": [{
        "latitude": "17.3850",
        "longitude": "78.4867",
        "name": "Hyderabad"
    },
    {
        "latitude": "17.4399",
        "longitude": "78.4983",
        "name": "Secunderabad"
    }]
}
```

I want to get the latlang values from url and show them on map as markers. If a marker is clicked it should show Title & spinet and also distance between my current location and the marker in a `TextView` provided below the map.

Any help please. Thank you.

Comment: what exactly is a problem? Getting values from JSON? Placing a marker on the map? Reacting on a marker click? Which of things above you fail to do?

Comment: placing on marker and reacting

Comment: ok, and now you need to spend something more than 15 seconds googling for `android map add marker` to find an answer to your question.

Comment: Looks like you just want to know how to fetch lat and lang from this JSON, am I right?

Comment: Adding marker with static is possible for me but getting values from url is a bit struggling. thank you

Comment: i have used gethttp method. but i am unaware of using results.  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse the data use the following way:

```
JSONArray response= null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> locationList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // Making a request to url and getting response
                String jsonStr = //The response in String format;

                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        response= jsonObj.getJSONArray("response");

                        // looping through All records
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            String latitude= c.getString("latitude");
                            String longitude= c.getString("longitude");

                            // tmp hashmap for single contact
                            HashMap<String, String> location_= new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            location_.put("latitude", latitude);
                            location_.put("longitude", longitude);
                            locationList.add(contact);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }
```

Now you got all the latitude and longitude in the **locationList** hashmap. Iterate through it and plot them in Google Map.

```
for(i=0;i<locationlist.size();i++)
{
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        resultp = locationlist.get(i);
    String lat=resultp.get("latitude");
    String lon=resultp.get("longitude");
    //Plot latitude and longitude in the map
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
GoogleMap map = ... // get a map.
   // Add a marker at San Francisco.
    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
   .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
   .title("San Francisco");

   private Map<K, V> multiMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_params = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

   JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject("Your Response");
   if(jobj.has("response")
   {
        JSONArray object = jsonArray.getJSONArray("response");
        for(int i = 0 ; i <object.isze ; i++)
        {
               JSONObject jsonObject = object.getJSONObject(i);
               String latitude = jsonObject .getString("latitude");
               String longitude= jsonObject .getString("longitude");
               String name= jsonObject .getString("name");
               multiMap.put("latitude ",latitude);
               multiMap.put("longitude",longitude);
               multiMap.put("name",name);

               list_params.add(multiMap);
         }

   }
```

Comment: @CharanReddy after you get long and lat from JSON, just put them instead constants in this code

Comment: this helps and the other i want is to show more than one marker at a time as url have two various locations.

Comment: try this solution

Comment: @CharanReddy, if you want two markers - run the code twice